# Firebase Storage Indexing

Tags: firebase, robots.txt, firebase-storage

My Firebase Storage loaded imgs keep getting blocked by https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/robots.txt when trying to be indexed. There is nothing private on these imgs to be blocked, so is there a way to unblock them? I've tried to upload my own robots.txt to the bucket root but it seems this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're trying to use something like the Twitterbot? Would be interested to hear more about the use case.

The good news is that we just removed our `robots.txt` file and will deploy this change in the next backend release, so bots will be allowed to crawl your bucket soon. Happy to update this thread once things are in production :)

Comment: Nope, just Googlebot. But my storage files are mainly public blog entry imgs so it makes sense to let it crawl them. That's nice, I'll wait until the next update then. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

that's great news! In my case it's Twitterbot that's been unable to follow Firebase Storage image links, therefore unable to display my CMS' preview images in shared Twitter Cards. I think you answered a question about that on the Twitter forums (I'm commenting here because that thread's been closed). Thanks also for saying you'll report back here when the change has been rolled out; any chance you can give a rough estimate, though? Like, is it likely to be months rather than weeks (or days!)?

Cheers.